# LinkedIn Contacts have blank LinkedInID C# .net

Tags: linkedin-api

So I'm doing this call.

ContactProfile p = null;

p = (from allP in Contacts where allP.LinkedInID == ID select allP).FirstOrDefault();

And sometimes the LinkedInID is present for certain users and others it is not.  Which is making my data appear randomly.  Is there a reason why a LinkInID would come back blank?

Answer (score 0):

If a contact has decided to not share their information with 3rd party developers, their information will be returned as "private".

An example is:

```
<person>
    <id>private</id>
    <first-name>private</first-name>
    <last-name>private</last-name>
  </person>
```

Is this what you are seeing?